# pptp vpn connected and tunnel is established but doesnot work

Tags: vpn, pptp

I have setup the pptp vpn connection manually in

/etc/ppp/peers/myvpn

and its contents are

```
pty "pptp <host> --nolaunchpppd"
name myusername
remotename myvpn
linkname myvpn 
ipparam myvpn
usepeerdns
require-mppe
file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
```

i have also set the /etc/ppp/chap-secrets file

Problem is i can connect to this vpn connection using

```
pon myvpn nodetach
```

But cannot access to any machines in that network.

I even get the IP for ppp0 when viewed using ifconfig command

But when I make the VPN connection using NetworkManager applet it works without any problem. I really need this VPN to work from manual settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this problem , many many thanks to @etagenklo

I just need to route the ip traffic to go through the vpn and that was really easy,

If you are stuck at this you can use this link. here is the [a link](https://serverfault.com/questions/489697/how-to-manually-setup-pptp-vpn-in-linux)

And Thanks again for the help "etagenklo"